# My Sass code keeps breaking when I try to add partials

Tags: css, sass, visual-studio-code

I'm learning Sass and working with a live Sass compiler on my vsCode, Mac OS.

When I break my Sass code into partials it messes up my code, turns the SCSS extensions in the folder to CSS. I can go to the status bar and turn it back to SCSS but then when I make any changes on my code it turns it back to CSS and breaks it, you can see by the image below some files have the Sass icon a some have the # icon who do I stop this from happening?

Can someone please tell me how to configure it so it stops doing that?

[image]

Comment: Does it only change the icon or does it actually change your code too? Also, it might be useful if you post your active VSCode extensions so someone can verify.

Comment: it changes the code also; on my status bar the extension says css instead of sass, and it will not compile it. as far as the extension i’m using live sass compiler by Ritwick Dey.

Comment: I have installed the `live-sass` extension and for me it works fine! Do you include the partials properly and did you activate **watch mode**? Im running VSCode `v1.51.1` with Live Server `v5.6.1` and Live Sass Compiler `v3.0.0`